Netplan messing up network priority
I have PCI ethernet and USB ethernet on an Ubuntu machine. I want the USB ethernet interface to select a specific connection (to 10.42.0.1, name = UR) on boot automatically, but it selects the other one.
I have already set the metric:
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.128.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.10.128.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 enx000ec6954183
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx000ec6954183

But the netplan-id0 connection is selected.

I have tried editing the netplan files adding the UR connection as id0 and the existing id0 connection to id1, which makes it select the right connection on boot, but I can't connect to 10.42.0.1.
Netplan config:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        id0:
            match:
                name: enx000ec6954183
            dhcp4: false
            addresses:
                - 192.168.1.102/24

I have also tried:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        id0:
            match:
                name: enx000ec6954183
            dhcp4: false
            addresses:
                - 10.42.0.1/24
        id1:
            match:
                name: enx000ec6954183
            dhcp4: false
            addresses:
                - 192.168.1.102/24


can you provide your netplan config?

@JourneymanGeek I've added it to the question
